# Is it possible to change the default place Tasks are saved in Outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, windows-live

I'm using the Office Outlook Connector in Office 2007 to sync my Windows Live Mail to Outlook automatically. The Windows Live Mail profile for Outlook Connector contains a Tasks folder separate from the default Outlook one.

When I make new tasks in Outlook in the To-Do bar, it'll put the new tasks in the Outlook Tasks folder, but I'd like them to automatically go on my Windows Live Tasks folder.

So, is there any way to change the default place tasks are stored?

Answer (score 2):

Aren't tasks saved in the default mail folder? Since else here's something from the Microsoft site which let [you change the default Outlook folder:](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/883401)

Microsoft Office Outlook 2003 and Microsoft Outlook 2002 use a default location to create and to open a personal folders (.pst) file. However, if you want to use a different location as the default location to create and to open a .pst file, you can add the ForcePSTPath string value to the registry.

**Add the ForcePSTPath string value to the registry**

Important This section, method, or task contains steps that tell you how to modify the registry. However, serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. Therefore, make sure that you follow these steps carefully. For added protection, back up the registry before you modify it. Then, you can restore the registry if a problem occurs. For more information about how to back up and restore the registry, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
322756  How to back up and restore the registry in Windows

To change the default path that Outlook uses for a .pst file, add the ForcePSTPath string value to the registry. To do this, follow these steps:
 - Quit Outlook.
 - Click Start, and then click Run.
 - In the Open box, type regedit, and then click OK.
 - Locate and then select the following subkey in the registry.

- Outlook 2003 : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Outlook
- Outlook 2002 : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\10.0\Outlook
- With the Outlook subkey selected in step 4, point to New on the Edit menu, and then click String Value.
- Type ForcePSTPath, and then press ENTER.
- With the ForcePSTPath string value selected, click Modify on the Edit menu.
- In the Value data text box, type the drive letter and the full path of the location that you want Outlook 2002 to use when it creates or opens a .pst file, and then click OK.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to do this in my case. I had to go into Tools -> Account Settings, click on the account that has the Tasks folder I want to make default, and click "Set as Default" to make that account the default. This will make all the special folders in that account default, not just Tasks, so be careful with this.

Comment: This method also make this your default Email account, so if you also use Live Mail at work it will send mails from Live Mail instead of your work mail...